# How do I add a WPF User Control Library using C# to a WPF window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have

```
xmlns:TechLog="clr-namespace:TechLog;assembly=TechLog"
```

And

```
                <TabItem Header="Technician">
                <TabControl>

                    <TabItem Header="System log">
                        <TechLog:UserControl1></TechLog:UserControl1>
                    </TabItem>
```

How do I do this in the .cs file of the WPF instead using C#? I want to do it dynamically so I add them on the fly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using TechLog;

 ...

UserControl ctrl = new UserControl();
this.TabItem1.Content = UserControl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a name to the TabControl:

```
<TabItem Header="Technician">
   <TabControl x:Name="tabCtrl" />
</TabItem>
```

In code file:

Add using:

```
using TechLog;
```

Add tab:

```
   string header = "My tab header";
   var newTab = new TabItem() { Header = header };
   tabCtrl.Items.Add(newTab);
```

Comment: TabControl is an ItemsControl, so you can use the ItemContainerGenerator to generate your tabs from the content, but it's difficult to set the headers when you use this method.

Comment: How is it I add TabItems to the TabControl? Found http://www.redmondpie.com/adding-tabitem-at-runtime-in-a-c-wpf-application/ but the .items dont exist

Comment: The TabItems will be inside of TabControl.Items, unless you are doing something unusual with the ItemsSource property on the TabControl.